# How do I use a svg path as a favicon

Tags: html, css, svg

I want an svg as a favicon but I don't want to reference it as a separate file like so:

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

I want to put this icon I got from bootstrap as the icon without having to download it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
   <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 .5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.001 7.001 0 0 1 3.274 12.474l.601.602a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.708l-.746-.746A6.97 6.97 0 0 1 8 16a6.97 6.97 0 0 1-3.422-.892l-.746.746a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.708l.602-.602A7.001 7.001 0 0 1 7 2.07V1h-.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 .5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM11.613 1.86a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 3.527 3.527 8.035 8.035 0 0 0-3.527-3.527zM8.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.362l-1.429 2.38a.5.5 0 1 0 .858.515l1.5-2.5A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5.5z"/>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The format for a Favicon image must be 16x16 pixels or 32x32 pixels, using either 8-bit or 24-bit colors. The format of the image must be one of PNG (a W3C standard), GIF, or ICO. This is from the W3C website...  https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: I've seen this however: https://css-tricks.com/svg-favicons-and-all-the-fun-things-we-can-do-with-them/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-alarm-fill' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M6 .5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.001 7.001 0 0 1 3.274 12.474l.601.602a.5.5 0 0 1-.707.708l-.746-.746A6.97 6.97 0 0 1 8 16a6.97 6.97 0 0 1-3.422-.892l-.746.746a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.708l.602-.602A7.001 7.001 0 0 1 7 2.07V1h-.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 .5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM11.613 1.86a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 3.527 3.527 8.035 8.035 0 0 0-3.527-3.527zM8.5 5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.362l-1.429 2.38a.5.5 0 1 0 .858.515l1.5-2.5A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

Answer (score 3):

Only in CSS urls do the **<** and **>** need to be escaped. The only character that needs to be escaped is the **#** in color notations and links

`fill="currentColor"` does nothing; only when you use the SVG in the `<body>`

`sizes` attribute is not required, in my experiments

and the `type` attribute is no longer required [say the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

Those Bootstrap Icons are bloated, can be made smaller, by multiplying the paths and changing viewBox

Makes the HTML file: (added linebreaks  in the SVG only for demo purpose)

##Basecode

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link
   rel="icon"
   href="data:image/svg+xml,YOUR SVG HERE"
  />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

### Fullcode

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link
   rel="icon"
   href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 160 160'>
    <path d='M55 5a5 5 90 015-5h40a5 5 90 010 10h-10v11a70 70 90 0135 123l8 8a5 5 90 01-7 7l-9-9
     a70 70 90 01-37 11a70 70 90 01-37-11l-9 9a5 5 90 01-7-7l8-8a70 70 90 0135-123v-11h-10
     a5 5 90 01-5-5z
     m-46 49a25 25 90 1135-35a80 80 90 00-35 35z
     m126-44c-8 0-14 3-19 9a80 80 90 0135 35a25 25 90 00-16-44z
     m-50 40a5 5 90 00-10 0v39l-15 29a5 5 90 109 5l15-30a5 5 90 001-2v-40z'/>
   </svg>"
  />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```